# Fisher's Exact Test and bonferroni correction in r

Tags: r, fishers-exact-test, bonferroni

I try to find out whether there are significant differences in Categories between several groups.
My data looks like:

```
Cat  Gr1    Gr2    Gr3
A    125    13      0  
B    10     0       0  
C    87     15      4
D    178    10      1
E    6      0       0                       
F    16     2       0
G    3      23      0
H    261    63      0
```

The numbers are counts of occurrence.
Target: find out whether there are some significant differences between the tree groups.
I calculated with the data in r and performed a fishers exact test. Is it necessary to correct the p-values because of the multi comparison problem with a bonferroni corrector?
How I can do this in r?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What do you mean p-value**s**? If you've done a fisher test you should have gotten one p-value.

Comment: yes, my p-value is 0.05147.

Comment: So there is no need for correction then. You would adjust your p-values if you conducted multiple tests, but the fisher test is one test.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!